# How to display data for nested objects in a check box in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm having this issue where I want to display the correct answer in a check box in Rails, to no avail.

The structure is further complicated by the fact that my models are nested into one another so that Survey not only has_many, but also accepts_nested_attributes_for Questions and Questions has_many Choices similarly. The problem is that I'm simply not able to get the box checked for the correct answer.

The data are saved to the database as a boolean in a column called correct_choice and this code for the show action shows the check boxes, but the correct choice is not checked:

```
 <table class="col-md-10">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <% for question in @survey.questions do  %>
            <li><%= h question.content %></li> 
              <% for choice in question.choices do %>
              <li><%= h choice.content %>
                  <%= h check_box(:choice, :correct_choice ) %>
              <% end %>
              </li>
            </li>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </thead>  
</table>
```

I've read the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box), but I cannot figure out how to apply it to my case. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

This is the HTML that I get out:

```
    <table class="col-md-10">

    <thead>
      <tr>

            <li>Is this a question?</li> 
              <li>I&#39;m not big. I&#39;m having a breakdown.
                  <input name="correct_choice[content]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="correct_choice[content]" id="correct_answer_content" />
              <li>Come on, I&#39;m not big.
                  <input name="correct_choice[content]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="correct_choice[content]" id="correct_choice_content" />
              <li>Who is hungry?
                  <input name="correct_choice[content]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="correct_choice[content]" id="correct_choice_content" />
              <li>Pass the cheese, please.
                  <input name="correct_choice[content]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="correct_choice[content]" id="correct_choice_content" />
              </li>
            </li>
      </tr>
    </thead>  
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to make it a form? Or just display it as a checkbox?

Comment: No, I can display it as a form. It works without any problem simply by using the nested associations between the models, but somehow the check box fails me.

Comment: Can you show the html output? Render the page and inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to advice from @davidwessman. What he told me was to display the html and inspect. I did and compared to the html from the edit action (the one that works).

It then became clear that I needed to use the check_box_tag command instead of check_box. This is the code that I now use:

```
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <% for question in @survey.questions do  %>

          <li><%= h question.content %></li> 
            <% for choice in question.choices do %>
            <li><%= h choice.content %>
                <%= check_box_tag "correct_choice", "yes", answer.correct_choice %>
            <% end %>
            </li>
          </li>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```